# Can someone explain my this sentence about feedback systems?

Tags: control-engineering

The sentence is

> In a closed loop system when the loop gain grows typically we have an instability

Comment: You may want to add some references and context to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain the very basic sentence with a very basic idea what happens.

If your gain grows, that means you're amplifying the signal **more**.

By loop gain I assume they mean the total gain from the loop.  If that is growing constantly, and the loop is closed, every time you go around the loop your signal strength should increase.  A constantly increasing signal isn't stable behaviour.

[Wikipedia's article on positive feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_feedback) has a lot of information and more links to more information (where I'm sure you could find actual academic sources).